# Question Ideas for our blog

Tags: discussion, blog

Have ideas for a post you'd like to see on a site about web applications? Post them here as answers! Try to provide a concise title at the beginning, followed by a sentence or two if necessary, so we can quickly look through them. It's okay to post things whether or not you think you'd want to write them yourself.

This will help serve as proof of concept and interest for the blog. You might also like to have a look at the separate question about scope of the blog to get some general ideas for directions.

> Blatantly ripped from Jefromi's [Question ideas for our blog](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/question-ideas-for-our-blog) on Cooking

Comment: I'm honestly confused with the close activity lately on meta, is it that you just want close all posts that died off?

Comment: That doesn't necessarily equate to meta questions, nothing in that post highlights that.

Comment: Can you post a clean-up meta thread with all the posts that needs removal/locks instead? 

You aren't going to get the close votes required in a timely fashion (very very very low activity on meta).

So basically all you're doing is sending me notifications via StackExchange mobile app :)

Answer (score 2):

**How to check if an email you have been sent is from who it says** (mostly gmail related functions will be shown)

Will demonstrate different ways in GMail in which you can use to check if an email is from who it says it is.

Answer (score 1):

**How to to solve Dropbox's 2012 Dropquest Challenge.**

It would interesting to show how to use Dropbox and other web applications to finish all 24 chapters.

Comment: This was painful. Gave up after Soundcloud

Answer (score 1):

**How to maintain inbox zero in Gmail**

A productive post about filtering and shortcuts to keep the noise level down with email messages

Answer (score 0):

**An in-depth guide for using a wiki for software development**

There are many different systems out there so a post about scoping to those that are suitable for a software project would be helpful to some.

Answer (score 0):

**Advanced Twitter Search Tips and Tricks**

Regular Twitter search is only par at best at getting the information needed. Showing different option to searching and using Google, Snapbird and other services could be an experiment to see how well it works.